# Filtering the data based on Keyword Search

Tags: excel, search, indexing, filter, excel-formula

I want to print 3 columns of data from an existing multi-row array, but with a condition. the condition is to search small list of Keywords named as mP_Keywords(A11:A14) with the column B2:B7 and display only the found data. I am sure I have problem with this part ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$7;mP_Keywords))=TRUE) in my formula. Is it possible to print the data which is searched?

`=FILTER(INDEX($A$2:$D$7;SEQUENCE(ROWS($A$2:$D$7));{1\2\3});(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$7;mP_Keywords))=TRUE))`

[image: Sample_Data]

Comment: Please can you share some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Hi, I have added the Example and desired result as in G2:I5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, it seems you could try:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=FILTER(A2:C7,MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(TRANSPOSE(mP_Keywords),B2:B7)),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(mP_Keywords),,,0)),"")
```

Comment: perfect! A seemless solution

Comment: Is it also possible to print the other set of data with the help of keywords? As in the above example, Print the data which does not match with the mP_Keywords? So it will print Rows corresponding to Name1 DEF & JKL?

Comment: @Ushay, sure. Type `=0` right behind the `,,,0))` part to make it `,,,0))=0,"")`